# How do I generate an import lib for an exe using automake/autoconf/libtool?

Tags: plugins, dll, mingw, libtool

I am porting a Linux application with plugins to Windows using mingw-w64.  I would like to generate an import lib for the main application exe and link the plugin DLLs against this import lib so that plugins can use symbols from the exe.  This will allow me to load DLLs on Windows using the dlopen interface in win32-dlfcn.

What I'm not sure how to do is write autoconf, automake, or libtool rules to accomplish this.  Does anyone know how to write such rules, or know of another project where these rules are implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the best way is to go behind libtool's back.  Here are some extracts from my Makefile.am.

Conditionally include the `dlfcn.c` source.  You'll also have to update include path, and possibly place some `extern "C"` guards in the header file.

```
if HOST_MINGW32
bali_phy_SOURCES += dlfcn-win32/dlfcn.c
endif
```

You'll need to adjust the LDFLAGS of the main application so that an import library is generated as a by-product of compilation:

```
if HOST_LINUX
bali_phy_LDFLAGS = -rdynamic
else
if HOST_MINGW32
bali_phy_LDFLAGS = -Wl,--export-all-symbols,--out-implib=libbali-phy.dll.a
else
bali_phy_LDFLAGS =
endif
endif
```

To compile the plugin, pass flags directly to the linker in order to avoid explaining the import library to libtool.  You'll also have to add the directory containing your main application (here its `$(top_builddir)`) to the linker search path.

```
if HOST_MINGW32
EXTRADEPENDENCIES = bali-phy.exe
EXTRALDFLAGS = -L$(top_builddir) -Wl,libbali-phy.dll.a
else
EXTRADEPENDENCIES =
EXTRALDFLAGS =
endif

mod_la_SOURCES = computation/builtins/mod.C
mod_la_LDFLAGS = -module -shared -avoid-version -export-dynamic -no-undefined -enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc $(EXTRALDFLAGS)
mod_la_DEPENDENCIES = $(EXTRADEPENDENCIES)
```

The `_DEPENDENCIES` line makes the module depend on the main application, so that the main application and its import library are built first.

Comment: FTR, in case you are using `libtool` anyway, you can also use `libltdl` to load the modules. Also, the same `--out-implib` method also works for a library which loads plugins which in turn use functions from that library. If have put a proof of concept implementation of library-with-plugins at [github.com/ndim/ndim-portability-test](https://github.com/ndim/ndim-portability-test) which solves the linking issues I have always run into in the past (until I read this answer).